# コミュニティマネージャー退任のお知らせ

Tags: 討議

こんにちは、スタック・オーバーフロー インターナショナル コミュニティチーム マネージャーのガーザ ホアンです。今日は日本語コミュニティのみなさんに大切なお知らせがあります。

スタック・オーバーフロー 日本語版サイトのjmac氏が先週、コミュニティマネージャー役を退任することになりました。日本語コミュニティ立ち上げの際には中心点な役割を担ったjmac氏に感謝の意を表したいと思います。これからも、スタック・オーバーフロー 日本語コミュニティが Stack Exchange Network の中で重要な位置を占めることに、何ら変わりはありません。日本語を話す developer のみなさんが心地よく学び、共有し、そしてビルドできる、素晴らしい場所であり続けたいのです。

スタック・オーバーフロー 日本語版サイトのコミュニティマネージャーが新しく就任するまではモデレーター3名の協力を得てサイトを管理していく予定です。

私たちはこれまでと変わらずつながりを保ちながら、日本語コミュニティのさらなる発展に力を入れたいと考えています。新しいお知らせがあればすぐにメタサイトで共有します。その他大きな変更に関してもこちらでシェアしますので、今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします！

My name is Juan Garza and I am the Manager of the International Community Team.  I wanted to come today to share some important news.

Last week marked the end of Jmac’s role as the Community Manager for this site.  He was an integral part of the creation of this community and we will miss him.  While we have parted ways, this community will continue to be an important one in the Stack Exchange network.  We want to continue to provide a great place for Japanese speaking developers to learn, share and build.

Moving forward, we plan on looking for a community manager and will work towards filling this role as soon as we are able.  In the meantime, we will rely on the strengths of our moderators to help us maintain the site.  You should see very little interruption here.

In short, I realize that this is an important change to the community and I wanted to assure you that we are still as motivated and connected to you as we have ever been. I will continue to update you with news when they arise and will strive to keep you informed of any other major changes.

Answer (score 7):

最近のことですが、スタック・オーバーフローでは組織構造の再編が行われました。 
以前に「スタック・オーバーフロー 日本語版サイトのコミュニティマネージャー就任等の状況に変化があればすぐにみなさんにアップデートをする」とお伝えしていましたので、今それを行いたいと思います。

今後は、私が引き続き日本語版サイトのコミュニティマネージャー役を兼任し、日本のモデレーターチームに日々のオペレーションを頼る形をとります。私が日本語版サイトに登場することは今までと変わらずありませんが、モデレーターチームと共に日本語版サイトの成長をみていくこととなります。私はまた、ポルトガル語版、スペイン語版サイトのスタック・オーバーフロー コミュニティも、日本語版とあわせてマネージする予定です。これらのサイトもモデレーターチームの活動レベルが上がる予定です。

私たちには幸い、素晴らしいモデレーターチームが存在します。今後のサイトの成長においては彼らのリーダーシップに期待しています。日本語版サイトのコミュニティが全てのユーザーにとって心地よく学び、共有し、そしてビルドできる、素晴らしい場所であり続けるために、コミュニティとしての成長は欠かせません。 
前進するにあたってこの情報を共有することが大切だと思いました。もし何か質問がある場合はモデレーターチームと私にどうぞご連絡ください！